# Magento 2 Pipeline Deployment - problem with .gitignore

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to set M2 Pipeline Deployment for my store.

I set individual `.gitignore` files for all Systems (`Dev`, `Build`, `Staging` and `Production`) according to instructions available on Magento Dev Docs.

I use one Github repository `Origin` for all Systems. All of them (Systems) are on the same phisical server.

Now, when I do push from `Dev` to `Origin`, I push `.gitignore` there too. It is then pulled from `Origin` to `Build` when I do pull from `Build`. That's bad as `Build` `.gitignore` is overwritten.

How to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the same branch in repository then it always gets overwritten.